# How to share post to company page via Linkedin API?

Tags: php, api, laravel, linkedin-api

I can't do anything without your help.

My task is share post to LinkedIn on company page via LinkedIn API. GET request works fine for me, but when i try create POST request i get this error message:

```
file_get_contents(https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/3723615/shares?visbility%5Bcode%5D=anyone&amp;comment=test+comment): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 request#no_content_length
```

So.. it's a part of my code (this code i get from official docs):

```
public function index() {
    ....
    // This GET request works fine
    $company = $this->companyInfo('GET', '/v1/companies/universal-name=ovdwebdev');
    print_r($company);
    // This one give me error
    $post = $this->companyPost('POST', '/v1/companies/3723615/shares');
    exit;
}

private function companyInfo($method, $resource, $body = '') {
    $params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
        'format' => 'json',
    );

    // Need to use HTTPS
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
    // Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request
    $context = stream_context_create(
            array('http' =>
                array('method' => $method,
                )
            )
    );

    // Hocus Pocus
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // Native PHP object, please
    return json_decode($response);
}

private function getAuthorizationCode($api_key, $scope, $redirect_uri) {
    $params = array('response_type' => 'code',
        'client_id' => $api_key,
        'scope' => $scope,
        'state' => uniqid('', true), // unique long string
        'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    );

    // Authentication request
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?' . http_build_query($params);

    // Needed to identify request when it returns to us
    $_SESSION['state'] = $params['state'];

    // Redirect user to authenticate
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### file_get_contents using URL

See [the docs](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents);

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen](http://php.net/fopen) wrappers have been enabled. See [fopen()](http://php.net/fopen) for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

#### However,

With a `POST` request, you'd need to `POST` some data. With REST API, this is usually done in the body.

Your error; `no_content_length`

Perhaps look into [cURL](https://www.php.net/curl) - **Here's a quick sample I put together for you** - It's not tested, so read their [docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api).

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$strShare = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<share>  
  <comment>Check out the LinkedIn Share API!</comment>  
  <content> 
     <title>LinkedIn Developers Documentation On Using the Share API</title>  
    <description>Leverage the Share API to maximize engagement on user-generated content on LinkedIn</description> 
    <submitted-url>https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api</submitted-url> 
    <submitted-image-url>http://m3.licdn.com/media/p/3/000/124/1a6/089a29a.png</submitted-image-url> 
  </content> 
  <visibility> 
    <code>anyone</code> 
  </visibility>  
</share>
XML;

$objCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($objCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares");
curl_setopt($objCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($objCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($objCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strShare);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                        'Content-Type: application/xml',
                                        'Connection: Keep-Alive'
                                        ));
curl_setopt($objCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($objCurl);
curl_close($objCurl);

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r( $response, true );
echo '</pre>';
```

Perhaps you could look into [SOAP](https://www.php.net/soap) seeming as it's XML

Hope that helps!

Comment: This API drives me crazy. Now i get error with code 401 "Unknown authentication scheme", i must authenticate with OAuth?

Comment: Yes. Have a look https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication on steps to authenticate

Comment: I can get my company title and so one.. it's means i already authenticated. My access_token is "XXXXXX" in "curl_setopt($objCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/3723615/shares?oauth2_access_token=XXXXXX" that's right? Now i get this error message: "Couldn't parse share document: error: Unexpected end of file after null". In my application i use your code example..

Comment: I'll have a proper look tonight, and write a set-by-step guide :) I'll notify you later tonight once it's done.

Comment: heey.. :) you don't forget about me? :)

Comment: No sorry. I've been busy. I'll do it tonight :) (Skype: harry.sniko if you'd like to talk there, too)